# "Can't play this video" error on every device using videoview in android

Tags: android

The problem is when I run the app on any device (physical and emulator) an error appears "can't play this video". I tried almost everything available on stack overflow and several other websites and then I thought the problem might be with my android API (24) but I tried on several other devices having lower or higher API but it's not working.  I put video in my resource directory it's working but unable to play using url and device storage. Following code is working perfect with resource directory but I want to access video from my device storage (internal or sd card). It would be very helpful if anyone resolve this issue.
[Click to see the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JERoA.jpg)

**This is my java code**

```
 public void start(View v1)
{
    mc = new MediaController(this);
    dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    int height = dm.heightPixels;
    int width = dm.widthPixels;
    v.setMinimumHeight(height);
    v.setMinimumWidth(width);
    mc.setAnchorView(v);
    v.setMediaController(mc);
    v.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a9eF2Lu742Q"));
    //v.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://jal.amar.com.myvideoplayexample/" + R.raw.movie));
    //v.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(Environment.getRootDirectory()+"/movie.mp4"));
    v.requestFocus();
    v.start();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Video has started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**This is my xml**

```
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoview"
    android:layout_width="362dp"
    android:layout_height="433dp">
</VideoView>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    android:onClick="start"/>
```

**This is my manifest file**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="jal.amar.com.myvideoplayexample">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Video Lectures"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <!--android:screenOrientation="landscape"-->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in the url use https://www.youtube.com/embed/a9eF2Lu742Q 
 instead.

-Reason: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a9eF2Lu742Q is a html page not a video file

-Solution right click video and copy the link from the embedded code.

Another solution would be to use the Youtube SDK

Comment: Thanks for the help Mohammad. I tried embed method and still its not working. But my main task is to access video from the Device Storage.